# Django join query for permissions and group?

Tags: django, join, permissions, many-to-many

I want to somehow join a group with all my permissions.
I want to query ALL permissions, and for each permission query a boolean indicator if the group has it.
So assume this

```
group = Group.objects.get(pk=1) # specific group
```

Permission.objects.all().annotate( group has it ??)

```
group.permissions.all()
```

won't help since I want to query all permissions.

**UPDATE:**
Clear explanation:
Assume my Permission table is (pk values): 1, 2 ,3 - total three rows.
Group table: one group with pk=1.
Group-permission (many-to-many) table:   group with pk 1, has permission 1,2 (so two rows)

I want to display all the permissions, with an indicator near them whether the group has it.
So in our case I should get :
1  True
2  True
3  False

Cause the group don't have permission with pk=3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the below query would work for you

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, BooleanField

group_name = 'your group name'
Permission.objects.annotate(
    has_perm=Max(Case(
        When(group__name=group_name, then=1),
        default=0,
        output_field=BooleanField()
    ))
).values_list('name', 'has_perm').order_by('has_perm')
```

[Conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) were introduced in Django 1.8, and [aggregation (annotate)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/) is also well documented.

Comment: Forgot to say that this does work. Just a question- for what the Max is needed?

Comment: Cause without the max, I'm gettting duplicated results.. I don't understand why

Comment: `annotate` causes `group by`, in this case, based on `Permission.pk` (if there is a prior `values()` call, it will `group by` those columns). When debugging complex queries, it's helpful to look at the generated SQL , e.g.: `print Permission.objects.annotate(...).query`